# Get best selling or hot selling products list

Tags: product-list, magento-1.8, class

I am new to PHP. I am trying to get best selling products list using the code which I found in `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Dashboard_Tab_Products_Ordered` class from `_prepareCollection` method.

```
if ($this->getParam('website')) {
        $storeIds = Mage::app()->getWebsite($this->getParam('website'))->getStoreIds();
        $storeId = array_pop($storeIds);
    } else if ($this->getParam('group')) {
        $storeIds = Mage::app()->getGroup($this->getParam('group'))->getStoreIds();
        $storeId = array_pop($storeIds);
    } else {
        $storeId = (int)$this->getParam('store');
    }

    $_productCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/report_bestsellers_collection')
        ->setModel('catalog/product')
    ;                                
?>
```

But I can't get the best selling products list. I am getting something else(very big dump text) when I checked using

```
<?php echo Zend_Debug::dump($_productCollection); ?>
```

PS: $_productCollection is a variable which I suppose to store a array of products so that I can use it in foreach loop later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can iterate through `$_productCollection` and get the products.

```
foreach ($_productCollection as $product){
    //do something with $product
    //for example
    //Zend_Debug::dump($product->getData());
}
```

**[EDIT]**
Each product in the collection is not actually a product. It only contains some details about the ordered qty.
If you call `getData` on a product you get something like this:

```
Array
(
    [period] => 2013-01-01 // probably January 1st current year
    [qty_ordered] => 2.0000// qty ordered
    [product_id] => 176 // id of product
    [product_name] => PRODUCT NAME HERE
    [product_price] => 44.99 //product price here
)
```

To get the full product you may need to do this :

```
foreach ($_productCollection as $product){
    $p = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())->load($product->getProductId());
    //attach the ordered qty
    $p->setQtyOrdered($product->getQtyOrdered());
    //do something with $p
    //for example
    //Zend_Debug::dump($p->getData());
}
```

I know that it's not really OK to use `load` in a loop. It may cause performance issues, but if you don't have many products you should be OK.

Comment: It turned out that I don't have any best selling products in my admin yet. Anyway to add it manually, so that I can check whether my code is working or not?

Comment: Place an order then go to `Reports->Refresh Statistics` and refresh lifetime statistics for orders (or all).

Comment: it is my local host and it is freshly installed magento..

Comment: I am getting best selling products list in admin but not in my webpage through the above template.. I am getting five products with "magento" image and price as "0.00" in my web page.

Comment: @Mr_Green See my update.

Comment: yup working fine.. but only images of each product are not loading.. I think this has nothing to do with this.. or is it?

Comment: it is loading some default image I think `http://localhost/efk/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/51x51/d62dc84c296895ef24112313cc2edcd8/images/catalog/product/placeholder/image.jpg`... I am giving src to image like this: `src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($p, 'image')->resize(51,51); ?>"`.